# Autohotkey (AHK) web page select file dialog

Tags: autohotkey, html, web-controls

I have input on web page, which allows to select file:

```
<input name="amount_name" class="form-control" id="amount_input" aria-invalid="false" type="text" value="">
<input name="file_name" id="file_path" aria-invalid="false" type="file" value="">
<button class="btn btn-success" id="save_btn" type="submit"></button>
```

And I have file name. I need to put this file name as if user selected it and then press "submit" button. I do this:

```
amount := 10
file_path := "C:\tmp\1.txt"

    wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
    wb.Visible := True
    wb.Navigate("https://example.com")
    ;here i fill one input field, it works
    wb.document.getElementByID("amount_input").value := amount
    ;here i need to fill file name. in this edition it opens dialog, but I cant fill it. if i use .value - it just ignored
    wb.document.getElementByID("file_path").click()
    ;it submits form, work fine
    wb.document.getElementById("save_btn").click()
```

Comment: btw, if i manually choose file from dialog, then i can get it from .value. But if I set .value, and then read it - it returns empty value

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
wb.document.getElementByID("amount_input").innerText
```

Comment: yes, same result as .value, and same with both of them